# Redimensionar e gravar PNG com fundo transparente

Tags: php

Gravo uma imagem **PNG** com fundo transparente normalmente, mas quando utilizo este código para redimensionar a imagem ela fica com fundo preto e não transparente como estava antes de ser redimensionada:

```
include("resize-class.php");

$resizeObj = new resize("/home/roteirodoimovelc/public_html/cp/clientes/".$cliente."/marcadagua/".$nome_imagem."");
$resizeObj -> resizeImage("".$width."", "".$height."", 'exact');
$resizeObj -> saveImage("/home/roteirodoimovelc/public_html/cp/clientes/".$cliente."/marcadagua/".$nome_imagem."", 100);
```

O que pode ser?

Segue a classe utilizada:

```
<?php

   # ========================================================================#
   #
   #  Author:    Jarrod Oberto
   #  Version:   1.0
   #  Date:      17-Jan-10
   #  Purpose:   Resizes and saves image
   #  Requires : Requires PHP5, GD library.
   #  Usage Example:
   #                     include("classes/resize_class.php");
   #                     $resizeObj = new resize('images/cars/large/input.jpg');
   #                     $resizeObj -> resizeImage(150, 100, 0);
   #                     $resizeObj -> saveImage('images/cars/large/output.jpg', 100);
   #
   #
   # ========================================================================#


        Class resize
        {
            // *** Class variables
            private $image;
            private $width;
            private $height;
            private $imageResized;

            function __construct($fileName)
            {
                // *** Open up the file
                $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

                // *** Get width and height
                $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
                $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function openImage($file)
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                        break;
                    case '.gif':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                        break;
                    case '.png':
                        $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                        break;
                    default:
                        $img = false;
                        break;
                }
                return $img;
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
            {
                // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
                $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

                $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


                // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


                // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
                if ($option == 'crop') {
                    $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
                }
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
            {

               switch ($option)
                {
                    case 'exact':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'portrait':
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'landscape':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                        break;
                    case 'auto':
                        $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                    case 'crop':
                        $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                }
                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
            {
                $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
                $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
                return $newWidth;
            }

            private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
            {
                $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
                $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
                return $newHeight;
            }

            private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                if ($this->height < $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                }
                elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                }
                else
                // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
                {
                    if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    } else {
                        // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    }
                }

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {

                $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
                $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

                if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                    $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
                } else {
                    $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
                }

                $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
                $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
                $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
                $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

                $crop = $this->imageResized;
                //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

                // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
                $extension = strtolower($extension);

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                            imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.gif':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                            imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.png':
                        // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                        $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                        // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                        $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                             imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    // ... etc

                    default:
                        // *** No extension - No save.
                        break;
                }

                imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
            }


            ## --------------------------------------------------------

        }
?>
```

Comment: Você checou os requisitos, pelo que vi o código está correto, pode ser a "GD library" que não está instalada.

Comment: Não entendi o downvote a pergunta está completa, é apenas uma dúvida com alpha do png.... Assim que chegar em PC eu posto uma resposta . To no celular  +1 pra pergunta

Answer (score 1):

O problema é com o alpha, pra resolver isto você pode usar as funções `imagealphablending`, `imagesavealpha` e `imagecolorallocatealpha`.

Como descrito aqui [*imagepng() and transparency in GD library with PHP*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1705118/1518921) por exemplo:

```
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
```

Um exemplo de uso [How do I resize pngs with transparency in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279310/1518921):

```
<?php
$newImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nWidth, $nHeight);
imagealphablending($newImg, false);
imagesavealpha($newImg, true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($newImg, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $transparent);
imagecopyresampled($newImg, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $imgInfo[0], $imgInfo[1]);
```

No entanto se quiser adicionar uma marca d'água (copymerge) talvez seja necessário usar este exemplo (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecopymerge.php#88456), eu não sei ao certo se o problema com alpha foi corrigido ou melhorado, mas o código a seguir resolve o problema se for usar em versões mais antigas do php como 5.2 ou 5.3:

```
<?php 
/** 
* PNG ALPHA CHANNEL SUPPORT for imagecopymerge(); 
* This is a function like imagecopymerge but it handle alpha channel well!!! 
**/ 

// A fix to get a function like imagecopymerge WITH ALPHA SUPPORT 
// Main script by aiden dot mail at freemail dot hu 
// Transformed to imagecopymerge_alpha() by rodrigo dot polo at gmail dot com 
function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct){ 
    if(!isset($pct)){ 
        return false; 
    } 
    $pct /= 100; 
    // Get image width and height 
    $w = imagesx( $src_im ); 
    $h = imagesy( $src_im ); 
    // Turn alpha blending off 
    imagealphablending( $src_im, false ); 
    // Find the most opaque pixel in the image (the one with the smallest alpha value) 
    $minalpha = 127; 
    for( $x = 0; $x < $w; $x++ ) 
    for( $y = 0; $y < $h; $y++ ){ 
        $alpha = ( imagecolorat( $src_im, $x, $y ) >> 24 ) & 0xFF; 
        if( $alpha < $minalpha ){ 
            $minalpha = $alpha; 
        } 
    } 
    //loop through image pixels and modify alpha for each 
    for( $x = 0; $x < $w; $x++ ){ 
        for( $y = 0; $y < $h; $y++ ){ 
            //get current alpha value (represents the TANSPARENCY!) 
            $colorxy = imagecolorat( $src_im, $x, $y ); 
            $alpha = ( $colorxy >> 24 ) & 0xFF; 
            //calculate new alpha 
            if( $minalpha !== 127 ){ 
                $alpha = 127 + 127 * $pct * ( $alpha - 127 ) / ( 127 - $minalpha ); 
            } else { 
                $alpha += 127 * $pct; 
            } 
            //get the color index with new alpha 
            $alphacolorxy = imagecolorallocatealpha( $src_im, ( $colorxy >> 16 ) & 0xFF, ( $colorxy >> 8 ) & 0xFF, $colorxy & 0xFF, $alpha ); 
            //set pixel with the new color + opacity 
            if( !imagesetpixel( $src_im, $x, $y, $alphacolorxy ) ){ 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    // The image copy 
    imagecopy($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h); 
} 

// USAGE EXAMPLE: 
$img_a = imagecreatefrompng('image1.png'); 
$img_b = imagecreatefrompng('wm2.png'); 

// SAME COMMANDS: 
imagecopymerge_alpha($img_a, $img_b, 10, 10, 0, 0, imagesx($img_b), imagesy($img_b),50); 

// OUTPUT IMAGE: 
header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
imagesavealpha($img_a, true); 
imagepng($img_a, NULL);
```

Comment: Infelizmente a resposta não funcionou no meu caso, uma vez que esta implementação eu já havia testado e o fundo continua preto quando usado transparencia.

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini quando chegar em casa eu faço um exemplo completo ;)